# mute or disable Winform application System beep sound with C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, awesomium, cefsharp

I have a Winform Application written by c#.  It include a webkit control   in which my web app displays . The annoying thing is that when I double click some html elements such as an empty input（

```html
<input type='text'/>
```

）, the system ring a beep. It is so Annoying !  How to prevent that beep ? 
I had been searched whole day about preventing such beep.   One of solutions is using user32.dll as below:

```
public void SetVol(){
  p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  SendMessageW(p.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, p.Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
}}
```

It effect all  applications  but What I want is just only effect my own application.

There is another similar question on stackoverflow:  [Avoiding alert on key board shortcut of C# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487086/avoiding-alert-on-key-board-shortcut-of-c-sharp-winform)  . The difference is that  It is   keyboard leads to beep  but my case is a double click that leads to that beep.

Remark : The beep seems only happens in 64 Bit os.

So any solution to prevent or mute  beef when I double click , effecting just my own application , using c#.   I nearly mad by this question. Thank you in advance for your help !!!  Please..

Comment: I would submit a bug report/change request.  Annoying controls should be fixed, not worked around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id